# php simplexml load file

Tags: php, xml, json, simplexml

i have a problem of this error or how do i fix it, any help.

> Warning: simplexml_load_file() [function.simplexml-load-file]: I/O warning : failed to load external entity "`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?><response><psid /><date><![CDATA[2013-06-04]]></date><name /><email /><status><![CDATA[declined]]></status><message><![CDATA[This company has not yet been approved.]]></message><price>0</price></response>`"

i am using this line

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($json);
```

Comment: Is `$json` a json-encoded string? You should also `var_dump($json)` to ensure it's the string you're expecting.

Comment: Are you trying to load an XML **string** as a **file**? Try `simplexml_load_string($string)`.

Comment: tnx for your comments i already solve it using this $xml = simplexml_load_string($json, null, LIBXML_NOCDATA) it automatically removes the <![CDATA[ ]]>

Answer (score 1):

`$json` should contain a file name/path. Not XML.

Use `simplexml_load_string()` to load an XML string.

So try this in stead:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($json);
```

Also naming the variable json is weird as it suggests it will contain something to do with JSON. But JSON and XML are totally different things.

Comment: tnx for your comments i already solve it using this $xml = simplexml_load_string($json, null, LIBXML_NOCDATA) it automatically removes the <![CDATA[ ]]>